# How to create a better tailored, better-converting shopping experience?

Tags: checkout

Ever felt this way?

You think you escape the queues and wasted time of high street shopping, only to find that online shopping can be just as tedious.

Say I wish to buy online some product that can be emailed to me. Like software. Or concert tickets. Or an ebook.

What I want the (Magento) store to allow me to do:

1) I click-select my product from the home/landing page
  2) I am taken to the payment form (better: it's already on the page)
  3) I fill out my email address
  4) I enter card or PayPal details and press "Pay"
  5) I receive goods instantly by email
  6) I feel happy

What a lot of Magento sites still do most of the time is this:

a) I find myself having to succumb to the **outdated paradigm of a shopping cart** that I have to put stuff into and drag through the online store from page to page.

b) When I finally arrive at one of the many so-called one-page/one-step checkout extensions, I am **unnecessarily prompted** for billing address, phone number etc. ... Dear online store manager: you don’t need that information from me! [And you cannot call it one-step when I have to fill out that much!]

c) I am made to **register** with the store — why?

d) I spend time **waiting** for spinning AJAX throbbers to finish calculations for shipping costs and what have you — when there aren’t any!

Only some of the above steps are necessary some of the time.

If you want to stand out as a merchant, the common one-size-fits-all approach isn't cutting it anymore.

We need to better tailor a store's checkout process to the products that are being sold and the minimum information required from the shopper.

***How would you improve the old-fashioned Magento shopping UX for emailed/FTP'ed products and make online businesses convert better?***

Answer (score 0):

So in summary, it seems that the requirements for a modern generation shopping UX are:

**1a)** Don’t use a shopping cart model when your site (or a section of your site) has only a handful of products with no or few attributes. These can be more conveniently selected in a simple side bar. Yep, a multi-select box for your products, as opposed to an ordeal through a labyrinth. Take that shopping cart out the back and shoot it.
**1b)** Then a few text fields to type credit card and email below it. Nothing else!

**2a**) Don’t ask customers for an address or phone number when just an email will do. Customers hate filling out long forms. They will also wonder what you’re doing with their information.
**2b)** Allow an option of entering a billing address if the customer wants a full invoice.

So: *no cart* and *no big checkout page* with unnecessary fields on it.

Just a simple **minimalist block/sidebar**, where the shopper can tick the product(s) they want, together with a mini-payment section, all on 1 simple form that takes up only a quarter or so of the screen.

An added benefit of this approach is that time-wasting AJAX callbacks with spinning wheels to calculate shipment or what may aren't required. A single submit to the server followed by a confirmation page will do the job nicely.